# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' While starting loop

Tags: c#

I know my question seems very generic and basic but I can't seem to find the problem. When VS starts to debug my code at the declaration of the integer value "i" this error pops up:

[image: Error Image]

[image: Variables at the moment of error]

So I have tried to declare before the loop but same error remain. After that I have changed the type of variable, yet no change. But when I declared it between the "masaQuery = ..." part, it started throw error at the assigment part of the for loop. So I've changed it that I can trick it but still the same result:[image]

First Version Of the code :

```
        string[] masaQuery = new string[8];
        masaQuery[0] = uyelik;
        masaQuery[1] = ucretler;
        masaQuery[2] = masalar;
        masaQuery[3] = masaHareket;
        masaQuery[4] = log;
        masaQuery[5] = genelAyarlar;
        masaQuery[6] = adisyon;
        masaQuery[7] = direktAdisyon;
        masaQuery[8] = bekleyenListesi;
        masaQuery[9] = borclular;
        for (int i = 0; i < masaQuery.Length; i++)
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection(connStr))
            {
                c.Open();
                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(masaQuery[i], c))
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

Last Version of the code :

```
        string[] masaQuery = new string[9];
        masaQuery[0] = uyelik;
        masaQuery[1] = ucretler;
        masaQuery[2] = masalar;
        masaQuery[3] = masaHareket;
        masaQuery[4] = log;
        int i = 0;
        masaQuery[5] = genelAyarlar;
        masaQuery[6] = adisyon;
        masaQuery[7] = direktAdisyon;
        masaQuery[8] = bekleyenListesi;
        masaQuery[9] = borclular;

        for (; i < masaQuery.Length; i++)
        {
            var query = masaQuery[i];
            using (SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection(connStr))
            {
                c.Open();
                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, c))
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

Waiting for your answers.

Comment: An array of length 9 has elements that run from 0 - 8. **Not** 0 - 9.

Comment: To be clear, the line throwing the exception is `masaQuery[9] = borclular;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [array documentation in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/):

> - Arrays are zero indexed: an array with `n` elements is indexed from `0`    to `n-1`.

When you declare an array with `n` = 9, the array index actually assigned from `0` to `8`, and when you're using 9th index will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because that index does not exist.

Instead of using `n` = 9, use `n` = 10 instead:

```
string[] masaQuery = new string[10];
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
string[] masaQuery = new string[10];
```

You have 10 elements but you're only creating a string array that can hold 9 elements.